# How to programmatically tweak the MATE desktop?

Tags: 16.04, mate, automation, ubuntu-make

I am experimenting with Vagrant and Ansible to set up a standard development environment in a VM, based on Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

I am trying to reproduce some UI tweaks in my cookbook, for example : enable the "Advanced menu" option. In the UI, the path to this option is:

- Open the *MATE Tweak* application
- Choose *Interface* on the left panel
- Check the *Enable advanced menu* option.

What would be the way to achieve the same effect by scripting, edition of config file, or any other programmatic method executable from an Ansible cookbook ?

Comment: I think `dconf dump /` from `dconf-cli` package may help. Many examples of `dconf write ...` are available [here on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22dconf+write%22).